# What is the purpose of a U-SQL Reducer?

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I haven't been able to find any documentation or samples for the use of Reducers in U-SQL.

How is a Reducer different from an Applier, because from the function signatures, they both receive one row at a time.

My use case is in the following question:
[Azure Data Lake Analytics: Combine overlapping time duration using U-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35624870/azure-data-lake-analytics-combine-overlapping-time-duration-using-u-sql/35627288#35627288)

I have achieved this functionality with an Applier.

How can a reducer be more useful for this use case?

Answer (score 1):

Documentation for the reducer is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/azure/mt621336.aspx

It is basically a custom rowset level aggregator so it could be going over an ordered set of rows within a key.

In most cases, using Windowing expressions or user defined aggregators is preferable.

Can you share your solution on the other thread?

**UPDATED**: You can find a sample for a reducer here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mrys/2016/06/08/how-do-i-combine-overlapping-ranges-using-u-sql-introducing-u-sql-reducer-udos/

Comment: I did find the documentation on this link, although it outlines the syntactical use and the purpose of a reducer, it doesn't specify how it will be used to perform the intended operations.
Could you give an estimate to when we can expect a sample?

Comment: Also, I'll share the solution on the other thread as an abstract outline of the procedure I followed with the applier.

Comment: added a link to a sample :)